# A set of n equations that equal each other

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let's say I have 3 equations:
\begin{align*}
    75a + 5 = x\\
    101b + 2 = x\\
    163c + 3 = x
\end{align*}
How do I proceed to find the smallest $x$ where $x \geq 2000$ and $a,b,c$ are Natural numbers? Would that method work for $n$ equations?

**Alternatively (if this is a bad question)** what topic of math would help me solve this equation?

The result should be `237005`.

(unfortunately I have no idea what topic of math this question belongs to so apologies for bad tags)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  It says you can find a solution as long as the multipliers of $a,b,c$ are coprime.  The solutions will recur at intervals of $75 \cdot 101 \cdot 163$  The Wikipedia page gives several approaches to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your system can be written as
\begin{align}
& x \equiv5 \text{ mod } 75 \\
& x \equiv 2 \text{ mod } 101 \\
& x \equiv 3 \text{ mod }163
\end{align}

This is a system of congruences and can be solved using this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem - see paragraph on constructive proof.